# How do I make a generic dictionary for multiple types implementing the same interface?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm facing an issue with `Dictionary<ulong, IStoreableObject>`, the problem comes when 2 different types that implements `IStoreableObject` have the same Id, everything messes up.

I came out with something like this in order to "fix it" but I'm not sure if this is a bad design, thread unsafe or if there will be another kind of issues, maybe someone help me to figure out how do I properly separated dictionaries for different types that implement the same interface so if their ids collide there won't be issues? This is my code so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SqlExpress
{
    internal sealed class Cache<T> where T : IStoreableObject
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<ulong, T> _cache = new Dictionary<ulong, T>();
        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        private static Cache<T> _instance = null;

        internal static Cache<T> Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance is null)
                {
                    _instance = new Cache<T>();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private Cache() { }

        internal void AddOrUpdate(T obj)
        {
            if (_cache.ContainsKey(obj.Id))
            {
                _cache[obj.Id] = obj;
            }
            else
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _cache.Add(obj.Id, obj);
                }
            }
        }

        internal T Get(ulong id)
        {
            if (_cache.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return _cache[id];
            }
            return default(T);
        }

        internal void Remove(ulong id)
        {
            if (_cache.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                _cache.Remove(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected behavior:

Let's assume we have 2 Objects, `Foo` and `Bar`, they both implements `IStoreableObject`.

2+ Objects of Foo mustn't have the same Id, and 2+ Objects of Bar mustn't have the same Id either. Anyways, Foo and Bar caches should not related to each other so if an object in `Cache<Foo>` has the same id of another object in `Cache<Bar>`, then nothing bad should be happening. This can't be done with `Dictionary<ulong, IStoreableObject>` since all underlying types are in the same cache, I want them on different caches and each cache should exists once, I mean, only 1 `Cache<Foo>` should exists as well as 1 `Cache<Bar>`.

Comment: You haven't described how you want to the code to behave if two objects have the same id. That's important information, both to you and to us, so start there. Leave the code out of it to begin with, just tell us, what should happen if you try to add a second object with the same id to the same cache?

Comment: You can consider Lookup<TKey,TElement> class in order to store several objects under the same key
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Use the type `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<ulong, IStoreableObject>>` or `Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<Type, IStoreableObject>>`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I've updated it to add expected behavior

SzymonTomczyk / Enigmativity 

Wouldn't those be expensive in performance? I already considered them but I was unsure because of performance...

Comment: Not sure I understand the premise here. Presumably you've declared your cache variable as `Cache<Foo>`, how can you add `Bar` objects to it? ie. this: `var cache = new Cache<Foo>(); cache.Add(new Bar(42));` shouldn't this produce a compiler error, cannot cast `Bar` to `Foo` or some such?

Comment: _Wouldn't those be expensive in performance?_  - no. Dictionary look ups are pretty quick. Another alternative is to create another key that combines your `ulong` plus something to indicate the type. Now they have no conflicting keys. Something like `var key = $"{id}_{item.GetType().Name"` and then you have a `Dictionary<string, IStoreableObject>`

Comment: If the two caches shouldn't be related to each other then what possible benefit could there be to trying to put them both in one collection together? Also, if you use the type to create the key, that means you have to know the type to retrieve it from the cache, which defeats the purpose of a common interface.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen And that's how I expect it to work, when it was a `Dictionary<ulong, IStoreableObject>` you could add `Foo` and `Bar` in the same Cache with the same Id, which causes invalid cast exception if you are expecting `Bar` to come but `Foo` overrided it because of Id collision, and many other issues...

Comment: But you cannot do that because you're taking your objects in through `AddOrUpdate`, which is typed to `T`, not to `IStorableObject`. There's some pieces missing here.

Comment: Instead of doing what @Enigmativity suggests. Can you create a `Cache<T>` instance per type: `var fooCache = new Cache<Foo>()`, `var barCache = new Cache<Bar>()` or is that too limited for your use-case?

Comment: @MattBurland I'm going to considere it, I don't mind nano/micro seconds, but won't it hurt performance with, let's say, 10k objects?

Comment: @Housy The thing is, this is a cache for a public library, so I can't manually create cache of types I don't know.

Comment: Then you need to include the type in the key somehow. You could use a native tuple: `Dictionary<(Type, ulong), T>`, should be pretty fast.

Comment: @Housy okay I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the only way to prevent duplicate keys is by including the `Type` in the key somehow.

You can do that by nesting dictionaries, like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<ulong, T>> _cache
```

But I would probably use a `ValueTuple`:

```
Dictionary<(Type, ulong), T> _cache
```

There also is a string concatenation approach `$"{typeof(T).Name}_{id}"`, but that again can generate duplicates if the type happens to have the same name but lives in a separate namespace. So it's best to consider the complete `Type`.

Also, consider using `ConcurrentDictionary` as it seems like you're in a multi-threaded environment here.